# Smartphone as a server

Tags: javascript, python, android, server, smartphone

I want to deploy a low-weight chat bot written in *python* and wondering if there is a way to keep the bot constantly online without having to host it on a paid cloud service.

As nowadays smartphones do have a decent hardware (CPU, RAM), are online and turned on the majority of the time, following question came up:

Is there any way to use an (android) smartphone as a **server** for python/JS/etc applications?

Comment: smartforn would have the same problems as local computer - it would need static IP and redirections and open ports in router (your router and your Internet Provider routers)

Comment: you could first test your code on local computer and use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to serve it in internet. Free version serve change adress when you restart it but if you run it once then it will have the same address all time.

Comment: some portals have free servers but with some restrictions - but for test it can be still good: [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/),

Comment: You can make a server of your Android phone but it can only be reached by clients from internet if the phone is in a wifi network that has internet. If the phone uses the simcard for internet your server is unreachable as your cellphone provider will block incoming connections.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Termux.

The steps varies depending on what dependencies your application is reyling on. 
Here is an example project that utilizes Termux. It's a Python application that also runs a small node.js script. It utilizes the phone storage for downloads.
https://github.com/dipu-bd/lightnovel-crawler#a3-termux-android

With Termux you get a linux like environment. You can find more about Termux here:
https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Main_Page
https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Differences_from_Linux